# Maven plugin failed after upgrading Jenkins to 1.505

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have upgraded my Jenkins server to 1.505 but unexpectedly building with Maven plugin is not working and it throws an exception in the Jenkins logs

```
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/ivy/AntIvyBuildWrapper
```

and after an hour googling this issue I found that Maven plugin guys upgrade their code base and it failed on an "optional" dependency, so I added the "optional plugin" but still it fails silently without any exception in the Jenkins logs.

the error appears on the console log is `ERROR: Couldn't find Maven executable.`

any hints ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new maven plugin adds a new option to the Jobs I have (under the build section -> Invoke Maven 3 there is a new field called Maven version).

So what we need to do is open each job configuration page and hit the save button in order to save the default value and it will solve the problem.