# Jenkins: ERROR: Couldn't find Maven executable

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I want to run a maven task with jenkins so i installed maven with `sudo apt-get install maven` command in linux and then in jenkins configurations i filled maven part like this:

[image]

but when i want to run the task i get this output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /home/services/xebium
ERROR: Couldn't find Maven executable.
/home/services/xebium
Can't find target file: out/*.xml with working directory: /home/services/xebium
Reading results as UTF-8 from /home/services/xebium/out/result.xml
Parsing results...
```

as you can see it couldn't find maven and though couldn't run the maven goal!
anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

From your snapshot it seems you haven't checked the *Install automatically* option which should be checked when you add Maven to Jenkins.

So check that option, install maven and try issuing the build again.

Otherwise, you may try to download [the binaries](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) yourself, drop them under some path and change the maven home path to point to latter one. The aim is to avoid the `apt-get` isntallation.

Comment: "Install automatically" should be checked only when want from Jenkins to install maven automatically. @hasan has installed maven manually, so that option should not be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Your global maven configuration seems to be correct. I use the same, and it is working without any problems. I think, your Jenkins item configuration is wrong.

In build item in "Build" section please select "Invoke top-level Maven targets", select proper maven version. In your configuration it should be "My Maven". In "advance" set proper path to pom.xml file and set proper maven goals.

Please also check: [Maven plugin failed after upgrading Jenkins to 1.505](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415717/maven-plugin-failed-after-upgrading-jenkins-to-1-505)